# Editing a .jar file with a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have written an updater program for my friend to update another program I wrote for her as a going away gift. I have written all the needed code for retriving the class files that are updated from a server and holding them in temporary memory. What I need help with is having the program replace the class files in the first jar file so she doesn't have to do manual updates. Note: The main program is not running during update so no exploding jars.

Comment: Sounds like something you would do with [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start).

Comment: Mm hmm. If she's your friend, just give her a new jar--if you just give her another program she has to run a jar anyway, so clearly that isn't an issue. Or do it right and use a plugin architecture from the outset.

Comment: Is there something like a JAR wrapping framework for this kind of gifts? :-)

Comment: @DaveNewton I was planning on eventually linking the two together so that it would take two seconds instead of ten minutes with email, and email file size limits are an issue because this will enentually include data files that could exceed 25mb. Besides I was also planning an auto-update function so she wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @Taxes45 And I'm saying do it as a plugin system for the latter. Use any random file sharing site for the former. What types of functionality are you updating in the app you wrote for your friend?

Comment: @edalorzo Thanks. I have used Java Web Start for my schools robotics site and that is a great idea for running a jar file from a server, but this application is designed to be run locally so that it can be run even without wifi or a connection.

Comment: Let me describe this a little more. She said that she was going to talk to me all the time. So I made a program with my personality in it. Every update would include a new response desision class. This program also contains serveral moods, each has three data files one for responses, keys, and defualt responses. All of these files will have more added to them each update until they have a maximum of 100000 lines of text in each. I also wrote a GUI which will get some cosmetic updates every now and then including images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the app. has a GUI, deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers **'one click' installation**<sup>1</sup> for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, **automatic update**<sup>2</sup> (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

1. It is easy for the user.
2. Automatic update is built-in, all the deployer has to do is upload the new Jar.

Comment: Yeah, I decided in the end to create the final version as Java Web Start.

Comment: Glitchy computer is glitchy. My mouse stopped working and I navigated via keyboard to fix it. I will mark it now.

Answer (score 2):

If Java Web Start is not what you're looking for and if the `jar` executable is available on your friend's computer (either because a JDK is installed on your friend's machine or you distribute it with your application), you can run

> [`jar uf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html) *jar-file input-file(s)*

If you want to call the `jar` executable from within a Java program, just use [`Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). For a more in-depth discussion about updating a JAR via the `jar` executable, see Sun Developer Network's article ["Updating a JAR File."](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/update.html)

Comment: You sir have answered my entire question. Thank you.